# C# FolderBrowserDialog: Getting only the selected folder's name

Tags: c#

As the title states I need to get the last folder in the string my open folder dialog creates when a user selects a folder. For instance:

```
String folder;
FolderBrowserDialog fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
fbd.RootFolder = System.Environment.SpecialFolder.MyComputer;
if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    folder = fbd.SelectedPath;
}
```

I want to trim everything before the last "\" to leave me with the selected folder's name. Thank you for any help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `Path.GetFileName` for this:

```
folder = Path.GetFileName(fbd.SelectedPath);
```

This might seem counter-intuitive, but `Path.GetFileName()` returns all the text to the right of the final path separator.

Answer (score 4):

An alternative to David's answer is:

```
folder = new DirectoryInfo(fbd.SelectedPath).Name;
```

This is, in my opinion, easier to read but has the disadvantage that it needs to create an additional object (the `DirectioryInfo`).

Comment: @Steve, indeed it is. Thank you.